# Is it possible to overflow an ASImageNode in Texture?

Tags: ios, swift, textures, asyncdisplaykit

Before implementing Texture/AsyncDisplayKit, I used a negative bottom space constraint to have a background image overflow from the collection view header. This caused the header element to appear like it was underneath first row of collection view cells.

[image]

I cannot figure out how to do this with layoutSpecThatFits in Texture. So, is it possible or will I have to find a completely different way to show this overlapping header element?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand, do you try to do sticky header or what?

Comment: No. I've added an image as an example. I what that header with the text to disappear when scolling, like section headers do. And that works fine, but I cannot figure how to get the image to appear behind the first row of cells.

Comment: Its looks like you want add blue image under CollectionView, right?

Comment: Yes, and that blue image moves with the content. Not a sticky background.

Comment: Its looks like custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. But you can do `ASBackgroundLayoutSpec` for layout Blue Node under ASCollectionNode,  and overwrite `layout` property for stop calculation when u scrolling collectionNode, and do offset by manually.

Comment: Other advies, if u want change dynamically frame, u always can overwrite layout method, for disable ADK calculation

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thanks for the advice.